# Getting unexpected CA1901 warning for ChildWindowFromPointEx function

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winapi, pinvoke

When I use the code analysis feature in my Visual Studio project, I'm getting a unexpected [CA1901](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1901-p-invoke-declarations-should-be-portable?view=vs-2017) warning for [ChildWindowFromPointEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-childwindowfrompointex) and also for [RealChildWindowFromPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-realchildwindowfrompoint), at their parameters of type [POINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd162805(v%3Dvs.85)).

I just defined a structure with name **NativePoint** with **X** and **Y** fields as **Int32** type, which I'm using as an equivalent for those **POINT** parameters.

I understand what the portability means in terms of value size when running under x86 or x64, however, in this case I'm not sure how to solve this warning, because I'm using the same **NativePoint** structure for **POINT** parameters of other functions like for example: [ChildWindowFromPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-childwindowfrompoint), [ClientToScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-clienttoscreen), [GetCursorPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorpos) and many others, and code analysis is not warning about them, and they work when running on a x86 and x64 process.

In fact, **ChildWindowFromPoint** and **ChildWindowFromPointEx** only seems to differ by one additional parameter, both takes the same **POINT** structure as parameter so I don't understand why **ChildWindowFromPointEx** is warning about portability issues while for **ChildWindowFromPoint** is all fine.

My question is: in C# or VB.NET, how do I properly fix (not suppress) this warning for **ChildWindowFromPointEx** and **RealChildWindowFromPoint** functions?. Maybe I need to define another different **NativePoint** struct with different field types only to use with these two functions?. But why these two functions throws a warning while for **ChildWindowFromPoint** does not if both takes the same **POINT** (my **NativePoint**) structure?.

Note that I get the same warning for those two functions if I use [System.Drawing.Point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point?view=netframework-4.7.2) structure, but only for those two.

---

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="ChildWindowFromPointEx", SetLastError=false)]
public extern static IntPtr ChildWindowFromPointEx(IntPtr hwndParent,
                                              NativePoint point, 
                                                     uint flags);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="RealChildWindowFromPoint", SetLastError=false)]
public extern static IntPtr RealChildWindowFromPoint(IntPtr hwndParent, 
                                                NativePoint point);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct NativePoint {
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}
```

Comment: Seems a pretty bogus warning (have you tried HandleRef instead of IntPtr?). Microsoft itself suppresses a lot of theses, as you can see here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UnsafeNativeMethods.cs

Comment: You should be using [`System.Windows.Point`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.point) instead of defining your own struct.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau But at the end of the commentary I specify that using **System.Drawing.Point** produces the same warning.

Comment: @Simon Mourier you mean for the **hwndParent** parameter of type **HWND**?, yes, it produces same warning.

Comment: Maybe use `internal` instead of `public` in your declarations (or `private` if you don't plan on using these functions directly elsewhere). You shouldn't use `public` in any case. If you export something, export a wrapper for the function.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the suggestion but I'm aware about member visibility, those p/invokes should be visible/callable for users of an API. Writing a wrapper for every p/invoke is tedious, hehe.

Comment: They should not :) A wrapper doesn't break anything (well, you know...)

Comment: @ElektroStudios I said **System.Windows.Point**, not **System.Drawing.Point**. Two different things.

Comment: Sorry I just didn't read the "*.Windows.*" part in your comment, but to be honest I didn't knew that WPF class library had that POINT equivalent too. Anyway, I read in some StackOverflow answer by @Hans Passant that said **System.Drawing.Point** is a good candidate to supply the WinAPI POINT struct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After poking around in the responsible analysis assembly, there is a mismatch between the Windows API documentation and the data set used by the analysis plugin.

The rule thinks `RealChildWindowFromPoint` should have have 3 parameters of each 4 bytes, and `ChildWindowFromPointEx` 4 parameters of each 4 bytes on x86. `ChildWindowFromPoint` on the other hand is listed as having one 4 byte parameter and one 8 byte parameter as expected.

Indeed, declaring `RealChildWindowFromPoint` this way seems to satisfy the code analysis, but I don't know enough about the Windows API calling conventions to say whether this is actually a valid way of calling that method:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "RealChildWindowFromPoint", SetLastError = false)]
public static extern IntPtr RealChildWindowFromPoint(IntPtr hwndParent, int x, int y);
```

Considering that rules for `RealChildWindowFromPoint` and `ChildWindowFromPointEx` are missing data for the return value size as well as x64 declarations, while the data for `ChildWindowFromPoint` is complete, I would assume that this is simply a mistake in the data rather than an intentional recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Maybe someone should report all this to Microsoft team.